# The property of my model couldnot be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

**When i try to reset password in my project it throw exception.**
    Here is my **Model**

```
public class ResetPasswordConfirmModel
{
    public string Toke { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "New password")]
    public string NewPassword { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "confirm new password")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
```

**Account Controller**

```
 [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ResetPasswordConfirmation(ResetPasswordConfirmModel model)
    {
       if(WebSecurity.ResetPassword(model.Toke,model.NewPassword))
       {
           return RedirectToAction("PasswordResetSuccess");
       }
        return RedirectToAction("PasswordResetFailure");
    }
```

**Here is view which throw exception**

```
  @model Champiosnhip.WebUI.Models.ResetPasswordConfirmModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ResetPasswordConfirmation";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Confrim password reset</legend>
        <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(t => t.Toke)</div>
        <div>@Html.EditorFor(t => t.Toke)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(t => t.Toke)
        </div>
        @Html.Hidden("Toke", Model.Toke)

        <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(np=>np.NewPassword)</div>
        <div class="field-validation-valid">@Html.EditorFor(np=>np.NewPassword)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(np=>np.NewPassword)
        </div>
        <div class="label">@Html.LabelFor(cp=>cp.ConfirmPassword)</div>

      **<div>@Html.EditorFor(cp=>cp.ConfirmPassword)</div>**
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(cp=>cp.ConfirmPassword)
```

**Mvc4 Exception information**

```
      The property Champiosnhip.WebUI.Models.ResetPasswordConfirmModel.Password could not be found.
```

***Entire exception could be found at https://docs.google.com/document/d/13t-9A60sYqFR-gWqwkCSlHE8sovgARy-wie_o8FGhOg/edit?usp=sharing***

em.. my password porperty in Account Model

```
 public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
```

Comment: where is your `Password` property?

Answer (score 20):

I had a similar problem and just found the solution before starting to pull my hair out.
The problem is that in your Compare validation attribute the property is still named "Password" and not "NewPassword". Change it as below and everything will work fine:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
```

Comment: Ha ha ha ha. I made the same silly mistake. :) You saved me and my time.

Answer (score 0):

> "The property Champiosnhip.WebUI.Models.ResetPasswordConfirmModel.Password could not be found."

The error indicates that (1) there is no 'Password' property in your view model. (2) Something in your view expects one.

In your view, look for something like ...(m => m.Password). If it is there, then you either need to eliminate it, or add a property for the 'Password' field.

Comment: look again, there is no property password in ResetPasswordConfirmModel. Its not clear what the model RegisterModel has to do with his view

Comment: thank you all, and the solution to this problem has been add property
Password in ResetPasswordConfirmModel

Comment: an that's strange because this property is clearly never involved

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ResetPasswordConfirmModel
{
public string Toke { get; set; }

[StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", 
MinimumLength = 6)]
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "New password")]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Password)]
[Display(Name = "confirm new password")]
[System.Web.Mvc.Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```